# Does serial downvote reversion work network-wide?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I'm fairly sure I've just been serially downvoted after a dispute about one of my answers on [Chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/).

The downvotes began immediately after, and come within (from what I can tell) the span of half an hour or so, on posts I wrote months or years ago that rarely if ever get attention, across five different Stack Exchange sites.

Does the serial downvote reversion script take all Stack Exchange sites into account? Or does it only work per-site?

Answer (score 14):

It doesn't matter. I have my observations and suspicions on how the script works, but nobody outside SE actually knows this for sure. And SE is unlikely to reveal much more details than what is already known. The vote fraud tools are secret and SE generally doesn't reveal any more details about them than necessary.

The procedure for cases where the script doesn't catch problematic behaviour is always the same, you wait until 03:00 the next day and check your reptutation history. If the votes have been reversed, everything is good. If they are still there you can contact SE and ask them to investigate. Keep in mind that anything involving very few votes is unlikely to be undone by SE.

Comment: Well, fair enough; to a degree, though, you could say to almost any question on MSE "it doesn't matter: wait and see". I'm curious to know the answer and this is a Q&A! :) It's also a launching pad for suggesting that downvote reversion _becomes_ network-wide, if it turns out not to be already.